# npm returning 404 and 405 errors when connecting to Nexus 3

Tags: node.js, npm, nexus, nexus3

**Background:**

I have a new installation of Nexus OSS 3 with which I have configured a repository to proxy to the official NPM repo. I have added users and added 'npm Bearer Token Realm' to my list of active realms. Repository status is "Online - Remote Connection Pending..." and the user I'm trying to connect with currently has admin access.

**Problem:**

I am attempting to login to the repo from two different systems, each using different versions of node 0.10.x (currently required for dev needs) and npm (one that came packaged with node, one updated to current). On one system I get a 405 error with the following output:

```
    ~$ npm login --loglevel verbose --registry=https://repo.xxx.com/repository/xxxx-npm/
    npm info it worked if it ends with ok
    npm verb cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node',
    npm verb cli   '/usr/local/bin/npm',
    npm verb cli   'login',
    npm verb cli   '--loglevel',
    npm verb cli   'verbose',
    npm verb cli   '--registry=https://repo.xxx.com/repository/xxx-npm/' ]
    npm info using npm@1.4.28
    npm info using node@v0.10.36
    npm verb config Skipping project config: /home/ubuntu/.npmrc. (matches userconfig)
    Username: (user.name) 
    Password: (or leave unchanged) 
    Email: (this IS public) (user.name@xxx.com) 
    npm verb adduser before first PUT { name: 'user.name',
    npm verb adduser   password: 'XXXXX',
    npm verb adduser   email: 'user.name@xxx.com',
    npm verb adduser   _id: 'org.couchdb.user:user.name',
    npm verb adduser   type: 'user',
    npm verb adduser   roles: [],
    npm verb adduser   date: '2016-09-22T17:41:52.249Z' }
    npm verb request where is /-/user/org.couchdb.user:user.name
    npm verb request registry https://repo.xxx.com/
    npm verb request id f911025c53b0616e
    npm verb url raw /-/user/org.couchdb.user:user.name
    npm verb url resolving [ 'https://repo.xxx.com/',
    npm verb url resolving   './-/user/org.couchdb.user:user.name' ]
    npm verb url resolved https://repo.xxx.com/-/user/org.couchdb.user:user.name
    npm verb request where is https://repo.xxx.com/-/user/org.couchdb.user:user.name
    npm info trying registry request attempt 1 at 10:41:52
    npm http PUT https://repo.xxx.com/-/user/org.couchdb.user:user.name
    npm http 405 https://repo.xxx.com/-/user/org.couchdb.user:user.name
    npm verb headers { date: 'Thu, 22 Sep 2016 17:41:52 GMT',
    npm verb headers   server: 'Nexus/3.0.2-02 (OSS)',
    npm verb headers   'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN',
    npm verb headers   'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff',
    npm verb headers   connection: 'close' }
    npm verb adduser back [ '405 Method Not Allowed', null, undefined ]
    npm ERR! 405 Method Not Allowed
    npm verb exit [ 1, true ]
    npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

On the second system I get a 404 error with the following output:

```
    npm login --registry=https://repo.xxx.com/repository/xxx-npm/
    Username: user.name
    Password: 
    Email: (this IS public) user.name@xxx.com

    npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-91-generic
    npm ERR! argv "node" "/home/ubuntu/nvm/v0.10.46/bin/npm" "login" "--registry=https://repo.xxx.com/repository/xxx-npm/"
    npm ERR! node v0.10.46
    npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8
    npm ERR! code E404

    npm ERR! 404 Not Found

    npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
    npm ERR!     /home/ubuntu/xvela-app/npm-debug.log
```

And here is the npm-debug.log from that attempt:

```
    0 info it worked if it ends with ok
    1 verbose cli [ 'node',
    1 verbose cli   '/home/ubuntu/nvm/v0.10.46/bin/npm',
    1 verbose cli   'login',
    1 verbose cli   '--registry=https://repo.xxx.com/repository/xxx-npm/' ]
    2 info using npm@3.10.8
    3 info using node@v0.10.46
    4 verbose adduser before first PUT { _id: 'org.couchdb.user:user.name',
    4 verbose adduser   name: 'user.name',
    4 verbose adduser   password: 'XXXXX',
    4 verbose adduser   email: 'user.name@xxx.com',
    4 verbose adduser   type: 'user',
    4 verbose adduser   roles: [],
    4 verbose adduser   date: '2016-09-22T16:37:53.671Z' }
    5 verbose request uri https://repo.xxx.com/repository/xxx-npm/-/user/org.couchdb.user:user.name
    6 verbose request new user, so can't send auth
    7 info attempt registry request try #1 at 16:37:53
    8 verbose request id e00f9c93ae664e01
    9 http request PUT https://repo.xxx.com/repository/xxx-npm/-/user/org.couchdb.user:user.name
    10 http 404 https://repo.xxx.com/repository/xxx-npm/-/user/org.couchdb.user:user.name
    11 verbose headers { date: 'Thu, 22 Sep 2016 16:37:54 GMT',
    11 verbose headers   server: 'Nexus/3.0.2-02 (OSS)',
    11 verbose headers   'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN',
    11 verbose headers   'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff',
    11 verbose headers   connection: 'close' }
    12 verbose request invalidating /home/ubuntu/.npm/repo.xxx.com/repository/xxx-npm/-/user/org.couchdb.user_3Auser.name on PUT
    13 verbose adduser back [ { [Error: 404 Not Found] statusCode: 404, code: 'E404' },
    13 verbose adduser   null,
    13 verbose adduser   undefined ]
    14 verbose stack Error: 404 Not Found
    14 verbose stack     at makeError (/home/ubuntu/nvm/v0.10.46/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/request.js:302:12)
    14 verbose stack     at CachingRegistryClient.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/nvm/v0.10.46/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/request.js:253:9)
    14 verbose stack     at Request._callback (/home/ubuntu/nvm/v0.10.46/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/request.js:210:14)
    14 verbose stack     at Request.self.callback (/home/ubuntu/nvm/v0.10.46/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/request.js:187:22)
    14 verbose stack     at Request.emit (events.js:98:17)
    14 verbose stack     at Request.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/nvm/v0.10.46/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/request.js:1044:10)
    14 verbose stack     at Request.emit (events.js:95:17)
    14 verbose stack     at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/nvm/v0.10.46/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/request.js:965:12)
    14 verbose stack     at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:117:20)
    14 verbose stack     at _stream_readable.js:944:16
    15 verbose statusCode 404
    16 verbose cwd /home/ubuntu/xxx-app
    17 error Linux 3.13.0-91-generic
    18 error argv "node" "/home/ubuntu/nvm/v0.10.46/bin/npm" "login" "--registry=https://repo.xxx.com/repository/xxx-npm/"
    19 error node v0.10.46
    20 error npm  v3.10.8
    21 error code E404
    22 error 404 Not Found
    23 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I've wikigoogled the heck out of this and Nexus itself isn't showing any evidence of these connection attempts in it's logs. Any help would be much appreciated.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The npm login command currently doesn't work for proxy npm repositories (it does work for group and hosted repositories though).

https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-10149

That's getting fixed in the 3.1 release.

Try putting your proxy repo into a group repo, and using the group repo's URL.